# Debugging Mojo for Palm Pre with Eclipse & Aptana

Tags: aptana, palm-pre, mojo-sdk

I'm pretty new to Eclipse and Mojo (.NET guy).  I'm having difficulty debugging.  I can set breakpoints and switch to the "Debug" Perspective, but no matter what I can do (I am running in debug mode), I can't seem to get the IDE to stop at a breakpoint in the emulator. I'm sure it's a pretty newbie mistake with Eclipse.  Anyone have a good step by step I can follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to set a breakpoint in eclipse for use with the palm emulator.

As Gtompson83 mentioned, all we've got to work with is the gdb-style command line debugger that is included with the SDK.

Yes it's a pain.

I find it easier to attach to the [emulator via ssh](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1744) (scroll down to "Debugging" section) to view logging, and then just [using logging](http://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/mojo/classes/mojo-log.html) in your app to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I successfully got in via ssh and used the 'log' command, but what is the appropriate way to stop logging?  'quit', 'exit' etc. seem to be non-responsive.

Comment: ctrl-c will get you out of the logger.   But the app never "Stops logging", it's just whether or not anything is looking at the log output.

Answer (score 3):

Palm has a debugger as part of the command line tools. You can set break points and check variables.

[Debugger Info](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1672)

Answer (score 2):

I like using the Ares Debugger/Logger. It works even for code not developed using Ares.

After starting the debug mode in Eclipse (changed debug config for the app to have checked the checkboxes for Inspectable and Mojo debugging),
launch the following URL in your browser (I've had the best results with Google Chrome):

http://ares.palm.com/AresDebug/ (you can use also AresLog for logger)

For AresDebug you may need to adjust the Script Filter to start with whatever your appinfo.json file has for the "id" value, then press Get Scripts. Then you're basically good to go. You can select another *.js file and set breakpoints, etc.